# Using COUNT with MAX in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to find which customer has the most transactions. Transaction table has an foreign key that identifies each transaction with a customer. What I currently is the following code:

```
WITH Customers as (
   SELECT
       [CustName] as 'Customer',
       [TRANSACTION].[CustID] as 'Total # of Transactions'
   FROM [dbo].[CUSTOMER]
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[TRANSACTION]
   ON [CUSTOMER].[CustID] = [TRANSACTION].[CustID]
)
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE 'Total # of Transactions' = (SELECT MAX('Total # of Transactions') FROM Customers);
```

Two things are wrong:
1) The latter part of the code doesn't accept 'Total # of Transactions'. If I were to rename it to a single word, I could treat it kind of like a variable.
2) My last SELECT statement gives me a result of the customer and all their transactions, but doesn't give me a COUNT of those transactions. I'm not sure how to use COUNT in conjunction with MAX.

Comment: I am going to go out on a limb here..  Are you looking for a count of customers - like an overall count?  Then, are you looking for a distinct count?

Comment: I'm trying to find which customer has the most transactions in the database. I think I'm making this much more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: Do you just want the customer id, or what?  What if there are multiple customers that all have the maximum count, do you just want one `CustID` and will any do or do you want a list of all customers with that many transactions (i.e. 2 customers could be tied for the most transactions)?

Comment: I want all customers if there is a tie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner table just returns `CustID` as a total number of transactions?  You need to start by finding the total count for each customer.  Also for a column you can use `[Name]`, when you use apostrophes it thinks you are comparing a string.  If you want to return all customers with the highest count, you could use this:

```
WITH TransactionCounts as (
   SELECT
       CustID,
       COUNT(*) AS TransactionCount
   FROM [dbo].[TRANSACTION]
   GROUP BY CustID
)
SELECT TOP 1 CUSTOMER.*, TransactionCount
FROM TransactionCounts
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMER ON CUSTOMER.CustID = TransactionCounts.CustId
ORDER BY TransactionCount DESC

-- alternate to select all if multiple customers are tied for highest count
--WHERE TransactionCount = (SELECT MAX(TransactionCount) FROM TransactionCounts)
```

Comment: This won't work, your select statement does not have a `FROM`, and why have the join anyway... all you need is the count and the id.

Comment: Fixed.  The way the question's query is formed it looks like he wanted the count along with the customer output.  If you look, `Customers` is the query table, the table with customer data is `CUSTOMER`

Comment: Yes, I am wanting the customer's name listed alongside the total number of transactions.

Comment: Changed to use `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY` so you can add other criteria if you just want one result for tied counts, and left sub-select in a comment if you want all with tied counts.

Answer (score 1):

First select customers and transaction count.

Then select the largest one.

Them limit your select to that item.

Work you way from the inside out.

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE CustID =
(
  SELECT TOP 1 CustID 
  FROM (SELECT CustID, COUNT(*) AS TCOUNT
        FROM TRANSACTIONS
        GROUP BY CustID) T
  ORDER BY T.TCOUNT DESC
) TT
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you everything you need. To get the top customer just add `Top 1` to the select

```
WITH Customers as (
   SELECT
       [CustName] as Name
   FROM [dbo].[CUSTOMER]
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[TRANSACTION]
   ON [CUSTOMER].[CustID] = [TRANSACTION].[CustID]
)

-- to get count of transactions
Select Count(*) as count, Name
FROM Customers
Group by Name
Order By Count(*) desc
```

Comment: You sure `order by count(*) desc` will work?  Does not run on all SQLs

Comment: if that's true, which I've never seen. you may have to wrap it in another query and then order by the named `count`.

Comment: In the event that there is a tie for the Top 1, will this include both customers?

Comment: This will show all customers with their count of transactions.